# using react js in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, reactjs, babeljs

I am following this tutorial to build a new tab chrome extension ..
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

but when I attach

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

for rendering JSX using babel as suggested by the tutorial I get this error from the browser console.

"browser.min.js:4 Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:"."
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plHy4.jpg)

I know this is violating CSP directive but then again how can I use the latest reactJS using babel?

Comment: Include `browser.min.js` as a file in your extension, and link to that.  (I feel like this should be a duplicate of another question, but I can't find it.)  You can also use `"content_security_policy"` in your manifest, but that's more complicated.

Answer (score 39):

In your manifest.json file, you can try setting

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

I got the answer from [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1357). This got rid of the error for me, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about it to know about other implications, sorry.

Comment: Great.. I was facing similar problem.
It's working now with this solution.

Comment: I solved this problem using the default "production" mode of webpack.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` in my .env file totally fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here, Bruno's answer is more correct. Use the "production" mode. E.g. in Angular

`ng build --prod`